# Python Tkinter button for individual product and size

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am new to Python and Tkinter. I am trying to create a program where I want the user to press a drink and a drink size and a flavour. I want this information written to a database table when they press an add button

I don't know how to do this. Could someone please help?

I have tried creating a function for each individual command which runs when each button is pressed, but I have had to create a large else-if structure to map every possible drink and size combination. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
global small
global medium
global large
global Espresso
global Cappucino

small = False
medium = False
large = False
Espresso = False
Cappucino = False

def Espresso():
    global Espresso
    Espresso = True
def Cappucino():
    global Cappucino
    Cappucino = True
def sizeSmall():
    global small
    small = True
def sizeMedium():
    global medium
    medium = True
def sizeLarge():
    global large
    large = True

def add():
    global Espresso
    global Cappucino
    global small
    global medium
    global large

if Espresso == True and small == True:
        backend.insert("Espresso","small")
        Espresso = False
        small = False
    elif Espresso == True and medium == True:
        backend.insert("Espresso","medium")
        Espresso = False
        medium = False
    elif Espresso == True and large == True:
        backend.insert("Espresso","large")
        Espresso = False
        large = False
    elif Cappucino == True and small == True:
        backend.insert("Cappucino","small")
        Cappucino = False
        small = False
    elif Cappucino == True and medium == True:
        backend.insert("Cappucino","medium")
        Espresso = False
        small = False
    elif Cappucino == True and large == True:
        backend.insert("Cappucino","large")
        Cappucino = False

#Small button
smallImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/smallResized.png")
smallButton = Button(topFrame,image=smallImage,command=sizeSmall)
smallButton.grid(column=0,row=4,pady=(15,0))

#Medium Button
mediumImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/medium_Resized.png")
mediumButton = Button(topFrame,image=mediumImage,command=sizeMedium)
mediumButton.grid(column=1,row=4,pady=(15,0))

#Large button
largeImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/largeResized.png")
largeButton = Button(topFrame,image=largeImage,command=sizeLarge)
largeButton.grid(column=2,row=4,pady=(15,0))

#Add button
addImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/Function/addResized.png")
addButton = Button(topFrame,image=addImage,command=add)
addButton.grid(column=3,row=4,pady=(15,0),sticky=E)

#Cappucino Button
cappucinoImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/HotDrinks/cappucinoResized.png")
cappucinoButton = Button(topFrame,image=cappucinoImage,command=Cappucino)

#Espresso Button
espressoImage = PhotoImage(file="ResizedItemImages/HotDrinks/espressoResized.png")
espressoButton = Button(topFrame,image=espressoImage,command=Espresso)

#BACKEND MODULE
def insert(product,size):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("foods.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO food VALUES (NULL,?,?)",(product,size))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

window.title("Coffee System")
window.geometry("830x800")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe start with something less ambitious? Perhaps without a database, perhaps without so many options, perhaps using tuples to store the selection, and perhaps a selection using radio buttons? As I see it, reading through, half the code is irrelevant to the problem, or useless (not doing what you think it does), and the other half is missing!

Comment: It would help if you remove the images from this program _for the purpose of this question_. We don't have those images on our machines, and the images are irrelevant to the problem. Also, this code won't run. Some indentation is broken, and you've not defined what `topFrame` is.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried creating a function for each individual command which runs when each button is pressed, but I have had to create a large else-if structure to map every possible drink and size combination. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Yes, there is. The flavor and size buttons need to set a value rather than call a function. Then, your add button can get the values and save them to the database.

Since the flavor and sizes are exclusive choices (ie: you can only pick one size, and one flavor) you should use radiobuttons. Each group can share a single variable.

For example, start by defining all of the possible flavors and sizes. These should be the values you want to save to the database. We'll keep it simple and have the database values and the values that the user sees in the GUI be the same.

```
FLAVORS = ("Cappucino", "Espresso")
SIZES = ("Small", "Medium", "Large")
```

We also need to create a couple of variables to hold the current value. Since we want tkinter to be able to get and set the value, we'll use a `StringVar`:

```
flavorVar = tk.StringVar(value=FLAVORS[0])
sizeVar = tk.StringVar(value=SIZES[0])
```

We can create the radiobuttons in a loop rather than one at a time. This code assumes you've created a frame named `flavorFrame` and `sizeFrame` to hold the radiobuttons.

```
for flavor in FLAVORS:
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(flavorFrame, text=flavor, value=flavor, variable=flavorVar)
    rb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

for size in SIZES:
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(sizeFrame, text=size, value=size, variable=sizeVar)
    rb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
```

Finally, we need an add button, and the code to get the value and put it in the database. Instead of a database, for this example we'll simply print the value. This code assumes you've created a frame named `buttonFrame`.

```
def add():
    size = sizeVar.get()
    flavor = flavorVar.get()

    print("flavor: {}, size: {}".format(flavor, size))

addButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Add", command=add)
```

To save the value to the database, just replace the print statement with whatever code you want.

Putting it all together, here is the final version:

```
import tkinter as tk

FLAVORS = ("Cappucino", "Espresso")
SIZES = ("Small", "Medium", "Large")

def add():
    size = sizeVar.get()
    flavor = flavorVar.get()

    print("flavor: {}, size: {}".format(flavor, size))

root = tk.Tk()

flavorVar = tk.StringVar(value=FLAVORS[0])
sizeVar = tk.StringVar(value=SIZES[0])

flavorFrame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Flavor")
sizeFrame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Size")
buttonFrame = tk.Frame(root)

buttonFrame.pack(side="top")
flavorFrame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
sizeFrame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

for flavor in FLAVORS:
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(flavorFrame, text=flavor, value=flavor, variable=flavorVar)
    rb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

for size in SIZES:
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(sizeFrame, text=size, value=size, variable=sizeVar)
    rb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

addButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Add", command=add)
addButton.pack(side="left")

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Would it be possible to use normal buttons as I have attempted to try this using a Photo Image overlay on the buttons to make the GUI crisp? Such as a button for espresso, cappucino, the three quantities, and and add button?

Comment: @Stec: you can use images with radiobuttons. And yes, you can use normal buttons if you really need to, though it will require more code and make your code arguably a bit harder to understand. The main point here is that you don't need a huge `if` statement. Have the buttons store values, and have the `add` function retrieve those values. You can store the values however you want - buttons, radiobuttons, mouse clicks, keyboard bindings, whatever you want.